# Get value using INDEX and MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help in my formula, I'm getting `#VALUE!`.
I have 2 sheets, I need to get the data using 2 values, So I've searched and the solution is to use the INDEX and MATCH Function. I've tried that in my formula but I think I'm doing it wrong.

I have 3 columns in my Main Sheet,

[image: Main Sheet]

In the column `Total Amount` I need to insert the formula.

And this is my 2nd sheet. 3 columns also.

[image: FUND NAME DATE TOTAL AMOUNT FUND 1/10/2018 19,247,423.00 FUND 2/10/2018 64,223,123.00 FUND 3/10/2018 21,788,343.00 FUND 4/10/2018 55,534,489.00 FUND 5/10/2018 1,122,873.00]

And this is the formula that I've used,
`=INDEX(Q9:Q13,MATCH(O19&P19,O9:O13&P9:P13,0))`

I've tried to check using evaluate formula and I'm getting `#Value!` I don't know why.

Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to mention sheet name for index array like `=INDEX(Sheet2!Q9:Q13,MATCH(O19&P19,Sheet2!O9:O13&Sheet2!P9:P13,0))`. Then you need to enter the formula as an array formula as you are matching two column. Need to enter as `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. You can use `SUMIFS()` to get your output. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `SUMIF()` would be best fit for you in this case. Try below formula.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$Q$8:$Q$13,Sheet2!$O$8:$O$13,A1,Sheet2!$P$8:$P$13,B2)
```

[image]

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT()` like below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$Q$8:$Q$12)*(Sheet2!$O$8:$O$12=A2)*(Sheet2!$P$8:$P$12=B2))
```